# Should Pickle Slices be Above or Below the Hamburger

Tags: hamburgers

When making hamburgers that will be eaten in a bun should the pickle slices be placed above the hamburger like this:

[image: line drawing of hamburger]

Or should they be placed below the hamburger like here:

[image: line drawing of hamburger]

Of course, there are ancillary issues concerning lettuce, onion, tomato, fried egg, ketchup, mustard and mayo but let us just consider this for a hamburger with pickles and maybe a little ketchup.

Is there an *objective reason* to choose one or the other?

Comment: Serve them on the side?

Comment: Stuff on the bottom hits more taste buds than stuff on the top. Of course, with a burger, you've got to get past the bun first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you might guess there is not hard and fast rule for this.  It depends on when you want to have the flavor of the pickle hit your taste bud; before the savory or after the savory (meat).  Additionally it could be complicated by other condiments you have mentioned above.  However there is a bit of science you can employ here as well.  Pickles (assuming you are using dill) activate the sour taste buds in our mouth.  Savory (umami) is not as widely distributed as sour. So from that standpoint if you really like that savory flavor from a freshly grilled juicy burger, you would want to put the pickles underneath the meat.  If you prefer the pickle taste to be front and center place them on top.  I've included a reference for you as well.  Happy eating! http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0072592/

Comment: Some fast food hamburger chains may have preparation rules that they give to the workers that assemble the sandwiches. It would be interesting if someone with that experience were to comment.

Comment: If you have them on top and think you would prefer them on the bottom, turn the sandwich over and try it.

Comment: While I am a scientist by profession I put myself through college working at TGIFridays (7 years).  Pickles don't usually come on their burgers but for those that do it has less to do with taste than it does ease of assembly and presentation.  :)